# Double for loop not adding multiple event listeners

Tags: javascript

I'm basically trying to cycle through an `array` of classes and attach event listeners to each class.

My JS however only attaches an event listener to the last item in the array.

My only guess is that the inner `for` loop cannot attach eventListeners until the outer loop has finished.

```js
var buttonClasses = ['apple', 'pear'];
var buttonClassElements = []

for (var i = 0; i < buttonClasses.length; i++) {

  var buttonClass = buttonClasses[i];
  buttonClassElements[i] = document.getElementsByClassName(buttonClass);

  var currentElement = buttonClassElements[i];

  // Now cycle through the elements with the current class and add event listeners
  for (var j = 0; j < currentElement.length; j++) {
    currentElement[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('Clicked ' + buttonClass);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="apple">The Apple</div>
<div class="pear">The Pear</div>
```

Comment: *"My JS however only attaches an event listener to the last item in the array."* No, but you only ever see the last loop's value for `buttonClass`. The linked question's answers explain why and what to do about it.

Comment: Simple solution is to use `forEach` on each array instead of `for`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: I read the linked answer to the question, and it does suggest `forEach`, but also suggest using `let` if the browser permits. Thanks for marking as duplicate :)

Comment: @Modermo Note that `var x = document.getElementsByClassName(...)` does not have `forEach` method. You can emulate it by calling `Array.prototype.forEach(x, function(el) { ... });`.